# Foreign key constrains in mysql when trying to add foreign key relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I got two tables called activity and user. I need to make foreign key relationship with these two tables. username is the primary key of my user table which is a varchar value. But when I am trying to make the relationship I get a foreign key constrain error with mysql error code 1215. Below is my DDL statements related to two  tables I mentioned.

Can anybody please help me to resolve this.

thanks

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `activated` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `activationkey` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `resetpasswordkey` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`),
  UNIQUE KEY `user_id_UNIQUE` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE activity (
  activity_id          INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  activity_type_id     INT UNSIGNED,
  activity_property_id  INT UNSIGNED,
  added_by             varchar(50),
  updated_by           varchar(50),
  activity_code        VARCHAR(50),
  activity_description VARCHAR(100),
  start_date           TIMESTAMP NULL,
  end_date             TIMESTAMP NULL,
  start_time           VARCHAR(10),
  end_time             VARCHAR(10),
  added_date           TIMESTAMP NULL,
  updated_date         TIMESTAMP NULL,
  is_available         TINYINT(1),
  PRIMARY KEY (activity_id),

  CONSTRAINT fk_ADDED_BY_FOR_ACTIVITY FOREIGN KEY (added_by) REFERENCES user (username),
  CONSTRAINT fk_UPDATED_BY_FOR_ACTIVITY FOREIGN KEY (updated_by) REFERENCES user (username)
)
  ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1. Try out the below query.

```
    CREATE TABLE activity (
  activity_id          INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  activity_type_id     INT UNSIGNED,
  activity_property_id  INT UNSIGNED,
  added_by             VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  updated_by           VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  activity_code        VARCHAR(50),
  activity_description VARCHAR(100),
  start_date           TIMESTAMP NULL,
  end_date             TIMESTAMP NULL,
  start_time           VARCHAR(10),
  end_time             VARCHAR(10),
  added_date           TIMESTAMP NULL,
  updated_date         TIMESTAMP NULL,
  is_available         TINYINT(1),
  PRIMARY KEY (activity_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_ADDED_BY_FOR_ACTIVITY FOREIGN KEY (added_by) REFERENCES user (username),
  CONSTRAINT fk_UPDATED_BY_FOR_ACTIVITY FOREIGN KEY (updated_by) REFERENCES user (username)
)
  ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake is that FK column types don't match the PK column types. In particular, the character sets differ. Read the documentation sections re foreign keys.

> [13.1.18.6 Using FOREIGN KEY Constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)
>
> - Corresponding columns in the foreign key and the referenced key must have similar data types. *The size and sign of integer types must be the same.* The length of string types need not be the same. For nonbinary (character) string columns, the character set and collation must be the same.

So `activity` needs

```
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

You will also find

> In addition to `SHOW ERRORS`, in the event of a foreign key error involving InnoDB tables (usually Error 150 in the MySQL Server), you can obtain a detailed explanation of the most recent InnoDB foreign key error by checking the output of `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`.